# How to get different kde plots for different features?

Tags: python, visualization, kde-plasma

I have 15 features as X_1, X_2,....., X_15 and I want to create 15 different kde plots.

but when I use the following code, I get all plots in one graph.

```
for i in range(1,16):
    ax = sns.kdeplot(data = train["X_" + str(i)], shade = True)
    plt.title('X' + str(i))
```

Output: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZn2I.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to be slightly more explicit about initializing a new `Figure`:

```
for i in range(1,16):
    plt.figure()
    ax = sns.kdeplot(data = train["X_" + str(i)], shade=True)
    plt.title('X' + str(i))
```

Or

```
for i in range(1,16):
    fig, ax = plt.subplot()
    sns.kdeplot(data = train["X_" + str(i)], ax=ax, shade=True)
    ax.set_title('X' + str(i))
```